# How to suppress output from a kqlmagic query in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am using [kqlmagic](https://github.com/microsoft/jupyter-Kqlmagic) to execute KQL queries in my Jupyter notebook. While executing, kqlmagic prints output to the notebook such as:

```
 * forrest@loganalytics
Done (00:00.302): 1 records
1201 rows, truncated to display_limit of 0
```

This output ends up taking up half my screen. I would like to hide it and only display my final output, which is a matplotlib graph of the returned data.

Is it possible to disable printing this output from kqlmagic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't love this solution, but I was able to turn most of the output off using the following settings:

```
%config Kqlmagic.display_limit = -1 # don't display tables returned by Kqlmagic queries
%config Kqlmagic.show_query_time = False # don't display elapsed time of queries
%config Kqlmagic.show_conn_info = None # don't display the logged-in account
```

Unfortunately it still prints some empty lines, but this is the best I could figure out so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your kql query on a distinct cell you can use `%%capture --no-stdout --no-stderr` magic in it.

It allows you to suppress output only for one specific cell, and didn't print any empty lines, but still not a beautiful solution.